# Differences in Installation for nagios 3/4 on Ubuntu with apt-get or build in?

Tags: networking, monitoring, installation, shell

I am new to nagios. I think my question is not only specific for nagios but overall regarding unix-systems.

There are many guides for Nagios Installation. Some of them use apt-get install nagios

Others use like build-in or  build-essential with compiler Installation?

What are the differences between these two installation?

What kind of effect could it have on my nagios installation or configuration?

Comment: It should have almost no effect. The Nagios configuration is handled through the /etc/nagios directory. Install it and get started. If you have specific questions as you do so, please ask.

Comment: I am asking because I dont know if I just use package installer I will be missing something  or mabye its  better to  build your software to lessen the  configuration process later on. Thats why I am asking this.

Answer (score 0):

Installing software via a package manager will install a precompiled binary and you will be good to go in a short duration of time. It also means you can easily upgrade and uninstall the software at a later date.

Building software yourself is more involved, and takes a longer amount of time, but you can enable features in the software that might not exist in the binary package. For some systems this might also be the only option.

For everyday use, you most likely always want to use a package manager.

Comment: So basically  the installation methode is the same . Just with building the software you can twerk on the options otherwise you are not able to.

Comment: Yes, however you lose all package manager capabilities by building yourself. No uninstall oreasy upgrade.